# "Subset of above not equal to" $ \subsetneqq $ Symbol

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I was reviewing my Algebra diary, and I noticed a symbol that I was not familiar to: $ \subsetneqq $.

After some research on the internet I eventually found it (through UNICODE), and found that the name was "Subset of above not equal to", but I don't understand it.

After some more search, I eventually find something here on stackexchange, but I find some conclusions a bit confusing for me.

If it means "Subset of above not equal to", how can it also mean "Subset properly included in"? Can we say that the symbol $ \subsetneqq $ equals the symbol $ \subset $?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to clarify, it's also very common (much moreso than the alterative, in my experience) to use $A \subset B$ to mean $A \subseteq B$ and $A < B$ for the relation you describe.

Comment: The name of the Unicode codepoint is purely descriptive of the symbol: It is a “subset of” symbol ($\subset$) above a “not equal” symbol ($\ne$); hence “subset of above not equal”.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means proper inclusion, i.e. $A\subsetneqq B$ if and only if $A\subseteq B$ and $A\neq B$. It is used rather than $\subset$ to emphasise that there is definitely not equality between the two sets.

Comment: So, does it means that if we say that A $ \subsetneqq $ B, we mean that A is a subset of B, but A is not equal to B?

Comment: That's right. I'll edit that into my answer.

Comment: It should be added that (1) this is done because in some places $\subset$ does not necessarily exclude the case $A\neq B$; and (2) more often we use $\subsetneq$, to denote this, but $\subsetneqq$ is a more explicit way to write that.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand it. We use this symbol more to create an emphasizing. I could just use the symbol $ \subset $. :D

Answer (score 17):

The symbol $\subset$ can be ambiguous.  $A\subset B$ usually allows the possibility that $A=B$, but some authors use it to mean that $A$ is a *proper* subset of $B$, so that $A\subset B$ implies $A\ne B$.  A variety of symbols have been invented to clear up this ambiguity and make explicit whether the $A=B$ possibility is intended:

$$\begin{array}{cl}
\text{Symbol} & A=B \text{ allowed?}\\
\subset & \text{probably?} \\
\subseteqq & \text{yes} \\
\subsetneqq & \text{no} \\
\subseteq & \text{yes} \\
\subsetneq & \text{no} 
\end{array}$$

The construction of the symbols should be clear: $A\subsetneqq B$ means that both $A\subset B$ and $A\ne B$.

The forms $\subseteq$ and $\subsetneq$ should be understood as abbreviations for the symbols $\subseteqq$ and $\subsetneqq$, which are too tall to fit into a line of text.

The Unicode name of $\subsetneqq$ is purely descriptive of what the symbol looks like: It is a “subset of” symbol ($\subset$) above a “not equal” symbol ($\neq$); hence the name is SUBSET OF ABOVE NOT EQUAL.  Unicode names can sometimes be a little hard to parse; just yesterday I was puzzled by MUSICAL SYMBOL WITH FINGERNAILS ().

Comment: +1 for not using images but unicode characters instead